# Split multi delimiter columns into multiple column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with 9 columns. One of the columns holds such string

```
Unique
3:107912234-107912321(-)
4:107913333-107913322(+)
Y:222002110-221002100(+)
MT:34330044-343123232(-)
X:838377373-834121212(+)
```

~ 400,000 rows with different strings. How can I split it into 4 different columns in the the same df, I can use `df.str(",")` if there was just one delimiter, but since this has different delimiters, I am lost.

expected output:

```
chr  start  end  strand
3    107912234 107912321 -
4    107913333 107913322 + 
Y    222002110 221002100 + 
MT   34330044  343123232 -
X    838377373 834121212 +
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df1 = df['Unique'].str.extract("(?P<ch>.*?):(?P<start>\d+)-(?P<end>\d+)\((?P<strand>[-+])", 
                               expand=True)
print (df1)
   ch      start        end strand
0   3  107912234  107912321      -
1   4  107913333  107913322      +
2   Y  222002110  221002100      +
3  MT   34330044  343123232      -
4   X  838377373  834121212      +
```

Thanks [A-Za-z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761344/split-multi-delimiter-columns-into-multiple-column/43761455?noredirect=1#comment74565598_43761455) for suggestion - if data are not always `+-` in `strand` column:

```
df1 = df['Unique'].str.extract("(?P<ch>.*?):(?P<start>\d+)-(?P<end>\d+)\((?P<strand>.*)\)", 
                              expand=True)
print (df1)
   ch      start        end strand
0   3  107912234  107912321      -
1   4  107913333  107913322      +
2   Y  222002110  221002100      +
3  MT   34330044  343123232      -
4   X  838377373  834121212      +
```

If need add to original `df` this columns use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
print (df.join(df1))
                     Unique  ch      start        end strand
0  3:107912234-107912321(-)   3  107912234  107912321      -
1  4:107913333-107913322(+)   4  107913333  107913322      +
2  Y:222002110-221002100(+)   Y  222002110  221002100      +
3  MT:34330044-343123232(-)  MT   34330044  343123232      -
4  X:838377373-834121212(+)   X  838377373  834121212      +
```

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - Thank you, I add your suggestion to code.

Comment: This is great as usual! I wasn't aware of usage of[-+], I would probably just use (.*?) Does it work with other characters as well?

Comment: @A-Za-z - Thanks, I add your suggestion to answer.

Comment: Oh I actually meant that I really liked the solution with [+-], just that I wan't aware of it :)

Comment: @jezrael saved my butt again! appreciate it..does add the new columns to the same df ?

Comment: can some one please explain whats going on with the code the only thing i could understand is <chr> would invoke new column.

Comment: @novicebioinforesearcher - I add solution to answer.

Comment: Hard question, but in my opinion this special code which is translated to column nmaes as says [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings).

Comment: @jezrael error `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'start', u'end', u'strand'], dtype='object')`  when i do this `df = (df.join(df1))`

Comment: There is problem same name in original df and new one, so need `df = df.join(df1,  lsuffix='_orig')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can split with the delimiters using regex to loop over your df

```
import re

x ='X:838377373-834121212(-)'
[s for s in re.split('\-(?=[0-9])|:|\(|\)', x) if s]
```

Comment: Great catch! My bad ... should have tested better ;)

Comment: I knew it could be done ... just correct it with tested code. Thanks for pushing me to try @ Steven Rumbalski