# using str.extract on string and intergers

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have asked a similar question before here [Split multi delimiter columns into multiple column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761344/split-multi-delimiter-columns-into-multiple-column)

Current problem

```
df
Unique
3:107912234-107912321(-):Cep290
4:107913333-107913322(+):Myra1
Y:222002110-221002100(+):Znpl1
MT:34330044-343123232(-):Brca2
X:838377373-834121212(+):AC007040.11
```

## code used that does not work

```
df_new = df['unique'].str.extract("(?P<chr>.*?):(?P<start>\d+)-(?P<end>\d+)\((?P<strand>[-+]:(?P<gene_n>[A-Za-z]d+))", expand=True)
```

## output

```
print(df_new.head(5))
   chr start  end strand gene_n
0  NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
1  NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
2  NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
3  NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
4  NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN
```

## question

How can i split the last string which is basically gene name  the possibilities of elements found there are

```
genename[. or -][numbers]
genename[numbers]
```

Comment: Your regex is using a non-raw string literal, and `[A-Za-z]d+` is definitely wrong.

Comment: Even with the raw literal, your regex is incorrect.

Comment: i also tried `[A-Za-z].*?` sorry regex it to confusing for me, i tried multiple operations but could not make this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex might solve the problem

```
df['Unique'].str.extract('(?P<chr>.*):(?P<start>\d+)-(?P<end>\d+)\((?P<strand>.*)\):(?P<gene_n>.*)')
```

You get

```
    chr start       end         strand  gene_n
0   3   107912234   107912321   -       Cep290
1   4   107913333   107913322   +       Myra1
2   Y   222002110   221002100   +       Znpl1
3   MT  34330044    343123232   -       Brca2
4   X   838377373   834121212   +       AC007040.11
```

Your solution was not handling the closing bracket for strand and the gene_n in this case is a mix of characters and numbers. Also the best way to handle alpha-numeric would be \w+, [A-Za-z]d+ doesn't work as pointed by others

Comment: this worked, i totally did not focus on the bracket thank you.

Comment: so is this a better way `df['Unique'].str.extract('(?P<chr>.*):(?P<start>\d+)-(?P<end>\d+)\((?P<strand>.*)\):(?P<gene_n> \w+, [A-Za-z]d+ )')`

Comment: Nope, just \w+. But even that won't work in this case as you have .11 in the last row so you should just stick to .*